# Computing candidate popularity provided a voter's list of all the candidates sorted by preference

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
void record_preferences(int ranks[]){                               // Update preferences given one voter's ranks

    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++){                       //Cycle through candidates
        for(int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++){                   //Cycle through rank list
            if((i == ranks[j]) && (j != candidate_count - 1)){      //If found and not last candidate
                for(int k = j + 1; k < candidate_count; k++){
                    preferences[i][ranks[k]]++;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

When I look at this custom function I made, I felt like there are too many `for` loops.

**Question:** Is there a way to make this code more efficient or possibly can I use recursion with it?

I tried formulating on how to use recursion, but I am getting stuck and can't seem to find a way.

Variables that can't be changed (but you can make more variables if you need to):

- `candidate_count` is a global variable and equal to 9
- `preferences[i][j]` is a global variable. # of voters who prefer Candidate i over Candidate j
- `ranks[]` is a local variable. This var stores user's input of their candidate ranking

Voting method is [Tideman Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranked_pairs). I'm specifically interested in the `record_preferences` function. For context, [the entire file](https://hastebin.com/raniwivejo.cpp):

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 9                                                       // Max number of candidates

int preferences[MAX][MAX];                                          // preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j

bool locked[MAX][MAX];                                              // locked[i][j] means i is locked in over j

typedef struct{                                                     // Each pair has a winner, loser
    int winner;
    int loser;
}pair;

string candidates[MAX];                                             // Array of candidates
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];

int pair_count;
int candidate_count;

bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]);                      // Function prototypes
void record_preferences(int ranks[]);
void add_pairs(void);
void sort_pairs(void);
void lock_pairs(void);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[]){
    if (argc <= 2){                                                 // Check for invalid usage
        printf("Usage: tideman [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    candidate_count = argc - 1;                                     // Populate array of candidates
    if (candidate_count > MAX){
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)    {
        candidates[i] = argv[i + 1];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++){                       // Clear graph of locked in pairs
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++){
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    pair_count = 0;
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++){                           // Query for votes
        int ranks[candidate_count];                                  // ranks[i] is voter's ith preference

        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++){                   // Query for each rank
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            if (!vote(j, name, ranks)){
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }

        record_preferences(ranks);

        printf("\n");
    }

    add_pairs();
    sort_pairs();
    lock_pairs();
    print_winner();
    return 0;
}

bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]){                      // Update ranks given a new vote
    // TODO
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++){
        if(strcmp(candidates[i], name) == 0){
            ranks[rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void record_preferences(int ranks[]){                               // Update preferences given one voter's ranks

    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++){                       //Cycle through candidates
        for(int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++){                   //Cycle through rank list
            if((i == ranks[j]) && (j != candidate_count - 1)){      //If found and not last candidate
                for(int k = j + 1; k < candidate_count; k++){
                    preferences[i][ranks[k]]++;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

void add_pairs(void){                                               // Record pairs of candidates where one is preferred over the other
    // TODO
    return;
}

void sort_pairs(void){                                              // Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
    // TODO
    return;
}

void lock_pairs(void){                                               // Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
    // TODO
    return;
}

void print_winner(void){                                             // Print the winner of the election
    // TODO
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pure Functions vs. Global Variables

You might want to consider making the function pure. That is to not use global variables. Pass those variables as additional arguments.

Although global variables an nonpure functions have their place in some use cases and in C in particular, like embeded systems, small self contained programs/modules, etc. But I would say in general it is a best practice to avoid them whenever possible. It's a good habit to not use globals and keep functions pure as the default way to code and only use them when you find yourself in situation where it seems like the only way (simple enough to be worth it) to go.

## Always False Condition

Here:

```
for(int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++){
  if((i == ranks[j]) && (j != candidate_count - 1)){
```

you iterate until `j < candidate_count`, but when `j == candidate_count - 1` you do nothing.

You should just iterate until `j < candidate_count - 1`.

To make it a little better you may compute the decrement before the loop to avoid decrementing the same value on every iteration. But the compiler may actually do this for you.

## Comments

It is very uncommon and invisible to keep comments aligned to the right.

They are easy to miss and they make the lines unnecesarily long. Everytime you have to scroll horizontally, it is uncomfortable. Whether it be because of long code or comments...

Just put them above the relevant line of code

```
// comment here
const char* code = "here";
```

## Efficiency

You are approaching the problem from the wrong side.

You might want to start with the ranks.

```
int least_preferred = candidate_count - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < least_preferred; ++i) {
  for (int j = i + 1; j < candidate_count; ++j) {
    ++(preferences[ranks[i]][ranks[j]]);
  }
} -
```

Maybe there is a faster solution that would require some more complex data structure, like hash tables, heaps, or something like that. I'm not sure if these basic data structures are available in standard C library. The last time I coded in C was at university and I was probably implementing those data structures myself :) But given the maximum number of candidates is 9, I wouldn't bother implementing something like that. As I see it this is more of an improvement of readability. And performance is not so important here because 9 candidates will be computed in less then a milisecond anyway.

Note that I iterate `i` only while less then `candidate_count - 1` because the least preferred canidate is not preferred over anyone and thus the inner loop would execute zero times because it would start at `j = i + 1 = candidate_count`.

Also note that I use pre-increment (`++i`) rather then post-increment (`i++`), just out of habit. It is no different in this case (when not part of a bigger expression). But in C++ you can overload these operators on objects and for post-increment you have to keep the old and new copy of the object, while pre-increment acts in-place and thus could be more effective. And so I believe it is a good habit to only use post-increment when it's feature is required.

## Recursion

Recursion is usualy easier to understand, but not better in performance (unless using tail recursion optimization).
I usualy try to avoid recursion. Of course this may require stacks, queues or other data structures.

Comment: I'm curious, is there a reason you decided to answer this question yet didn't consider it worthy of an upvote?